# Override woocommerce wc-class function

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm not good in WP and plugins and will need some help here. I've read that is possible to alter some WC core function with filters and action but probably I didn't understand this correctly. I want to simply delete the shipping price from my cart page `Total price` field.

The function which is in `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php` is:

```
protected function calculate_totals() {
    $this->set_total( 'total', round( $this->get_total( 'items_total', true ) + $this->get_total( 'fees_total', true ) + $this->get_total( 'shipping_total', true ) + array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( true ) ), 0 ) );
    $this->cart->set_total_tax( array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( false ) ) );

    // Allow plugins to hook and alter totals before final total is calculated.
    if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals' ) ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', $this->cart );
    }

    // Allow plugins to filter the grand total, and sum the cart totals in case of modifications.
    $this->cart->set_total( max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', $this->get_total( 'total' ), $this->cart ) ) );
}
```

I've tried to copy it to my child theme `function.php` file like this:

```
add_action('calculate_totals', 'my_calculate_totals');

function my_calculate_totals() 
{
        $this->set_total( 'total', round( $this->get_total( 'items_total', true ) + $this->get_total( 'fees_total', true ) + array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( true ) ), 0 ) );
        $this->cart->set_total_tax( array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( false ) ) );

        // Allow plugins to hook and alter totals before final total is calculated.
        if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals' ) ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', $this->cart );
        }

        // Allow plugins to filter the grand total, and sum the cart totals in case of modifications.
        $this->cart->set_total( max( 0, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', $this->get_total( 'total' ), $this->cart ) ) );
}
```

It doesn't work. Is this possible?

My goal is to just remove this from first line

```
$this->get_total( 'shipping_total', true )
```

UPDATE:

I have tried like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'my_calculate_totals');

function my_calculate_totals($cart = null) 
{
        $cart = new WC_Cart_Totals();
        $this->set_total( 'total', round( $this->get_total( 'items_total', true ) + $this->get_total( 'fees_total', true ) + array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( true ) ), 0 ) );
        $this->cart->set_total_tax( array_sum( $this->get_merged_taxes( false ) ) );

}
```

Got this error

> A valid WC_Cart object is required

Comment: Any suggestion with what and how to replace $this?

Comment: That `calculate_totals()` function is a method in the `WC_Cart_Totals` class and if you want to override that method, you need to extend that class. `$this` basically points to the class instance - e.g. `$instance = new WC_Cart_Totals();`, and from a global function, `$this` is not available - and as you've seen, throws a fatal error.

Comment: PS: Whomever you were replying to, he/she already deleted his/her comments; so you should as well....

Comment: @SallyCJ I've deleted the messages. Also tried with `$cart = new WC_Cart_Totals();` but got that object is required. Isn't the `$cart` object in this manner?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, either. There's no need to re-instantiate the class (in your case). And from what I could understand, you're trying to exclude the `shipping_total` from the calculation, right? Is the free shipping method not working for you, that you're manually removing the shipping *total*?

Comment: The free shipping is working fine but this is for other category of products where if is added in the cart has whole different method of delivery and shipping. For rest products is standard shipping which is available via plugin. So, basically I have added condition on my cart page which check what product is in the cart and showing different prices based on the product.

Comment: The problem is that the shipping plugin form my delivery company can't be turned off and always shows the total price calculated with shipping cost.

Comment: So for those specific products, you want to subtract the total shipping cost from the product price, or?

Comment: Yes, I want to show only the total products price excluding shipping cost. Product 1 cost $50, product 2 cost $25 so total = $75.

Comment: Try the `woocommerce_calculated_total` filter - if and when applicable, you can subtract the shipping total from the total price. See example [here](https://pastebin.com/caKB50nL).

Comment: Sorry, do I need to add this in function in my function.php?

Comment: Yes, `functions.php`.

Comment: Thanks but can't get it work.

Comment: How is it not working? What's your code?

Comment: @SallyCJ this is how I've done it (I've used the snipped from other question you helped me). I'm not sure if is "most optimized" variant but at least is working: https://pastebin.com/0GLnR9Yx

Comment: That's also how I'd do it, except you should use the `$total` that WooCommerce passes to the filter callback function, so the `$total = $cart_item->get_shipping_total();` is not necessary. I'm not asking you to use [this](https://pastebin.com/c13y4biH), but you can try it out.

Comment: Didn't know that about `$total`. Thank you!